# Why does my website's favicon show up as a red line?

Tags: html, web, favicon

My website favicon shows up in Chrome and Edge with a red line. This happens on Firefox and Safari on the Mac as well.

[image]

As far as I know, the only code I need to set the favicon is the following:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/static/sitefavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="/static/sitefavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

This is present in the HTML and the links work when I inspect the page, but the favicon shows up as a red line as in the above screenshot.

I have tried using direct links (i.e., with `https://` instead of relative links like those above) with no effect. I have also tried clearing my caches and using a different machine and this too seems to have no effect. If it matters, the website is powered by Django and hosted on AWS.

Comment: It might have something to do with the encoding of the actual image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-encoding the image as `png` and changing type to `image/png` fixed the issue.

Answer (score -3):

Try removing that leading slash:

```
href="static/sitefavicon.ico"
```